# Login options in Stackexchange account

Tags: support, login

When you login into Stack Overflow or any other site in the Stack Exchange network it provides couple of login options.

```
1. Login with StackExchange.com
2. Login with Google account
```

What is the difference between these two, which one is optimal. We currently use [2] for everything.

Comment: Just different OpenID providers. None is "optimal" do whatever suits you better. Think of that as different doors to the same house.

Comment: Who is "we"? You and your sock puppet accounts?

Comment: @CodyGray It usually keeps asking to create multiple accounts on each site we visit, so wan.ted to know if using Stackexchange account would be any better. If you don't feel like answering just buzz off, nobody needs your "expert" comments here. "we" means folks in our concern.

Comment: I'm not asking what your question is. I was asking who "we" refers to. Unless you have a psychiatric disorder, a plural pronoun implies that you have multiple accounts with different names, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are equally good.

Basically, both are [OpenID](http://enwp.org/OpenID) providers. You can create an account on http://openid.stackexchange.com and use that as a login (the SE login), or you can create a Google account and use that as a login.